# Property 'add' does not exist on type 'FontFaceSet'

Tags: javascript, typescript, font-face

I'm following the [Adding a font to a document or worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API#adding_a_font_to_a_document_or_worker) from the developer mozilla website.

This is the code they're sharing

```js
// Define a FontFace
const font = new FontFace("myfont", "url(myfont.woff)", {
  style: "italic",
  weight: "400",
  stretch: "condensed",
});

// Add to the document.fonts (FontFaceSet)
document.fonts.add(font);
```

But when I do exactly that, in my Angular app, I receive the following error

> Property 'add' does not exist on type 'FontFaceSet'.

Does somebody found a solution to it ?

#### My stack

*This seems to be a typescript error.*

- `"typescript": "^5.3.3"`

Comment: What is giving you this error? Is it your browser at runtime, or TS at compile-time? What versions of Angular/TS are you using? And which browser and browser version? This should work fine as far as I can see.

Comment: You may like to include an angular tag as the code seems fine in plain JS ( using a font url that I can access).

Comment: I'm having the same issue in a Vue project, this is a typescript error. TS version 5.3.2

Comment: code work. nothing error

Comment: Also in version 5.3, [the `FontFaceSet` interface extends `Set`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/release-5.3/src/lib/dom.iterable.generated.d.ts#L94) and [`Set` has an `add` property](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/release-5.3/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts#L75), so this should work fine. Have you overwritten the `FontFaceSet` or `Set` interfaces somewhere by any chance ([like suggested here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30984#issuecomment-581953895))? You could always use `(document as any).fonts.add(font)`.